# Microsoft Graph File Permission invite API not working always

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app to work with MS group Documents files.

For a public group, I am creating files with the app and sharing direct invite to a tenant user (Not a member of the group) using permission API:
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/Document.docx:/invite](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive_id%7D/root:/Document.docx:/invite)

I am observing it is giving success response always but permission is not always created for the file. I verified on the UI also. Sometimes, UI does not show the User in the Manage Permission list. The API behavior is inconsistent.

Once this situation  occurs, PATCH permission and GET specific permission fails for this File even if invite API response was success. PATCH permission fails with 400 error code.

I have tried this using MS Graph Explorer as well. I am observing this issue using the Graph Explorer as well.

Has anybody come across this issue and dealt with it?

[Edit] I have observed this issue for public group only. For User onedrive and private group drive I am not getting this issue.

Comment: what error you're getting?

Comment: PATCH fails with Bad Request - 400